# How to create a firewall that monitors all traffic

Tags: networking, firewall, network-monitoring, network-traffic

I currently have squid on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I can't figure out how to make Squid a transparent server on the network with a Asus RT-AC66U Merlin and how to make the server into a network wide firewall to prevent virus, malware, spyware, trojans, etc. from entering the network. Is there a way to configure this on the server itself by bridging the modem and router through Ubuntu? Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe if you setup samba v4 to be a AD server, and all the users have unique logins.  The username **might** be available.  However, if you have an android or etc smartphone it can't join the domain and the username won't be available.

Comment: Oh. . . I see; you are just trying to reinvent the wheel, right? Price would ***stay at $0*** yet complexity and piecing it all together.... priceless!!!

Comment: If you just need to simply ***log websites visited by who*** then you really don't need an OS routing firewall/proxy to keep track of that assuming you are the web server administrator. What do you ultimately need at the zero cost price point exactly?

Comment: In its original version your question got 4 close votes for being a request for a product/service.  You fixed that in your edit, however *now* it's too broad. Please consider reading [ask] and visit the [Help/on-topic] for info on writing a good question.

Answer (score 1):

To log http traffic by URL you can go with two methods:

1) Inline: Use [SQUID Proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/)
You can setup a transparent *inline* Squid Proxy to inspect and forward web traffic. This works by combining the proxy with a firewall that redirects traffic to the proxy ports. A basic version of this setup is [here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/LinuxRedirect).

For more complicated setups, Cisco's WCCP (Web Cache Communications Protocol) protocol can forward traffic directly from a router to your proxy (via GRE tunnels), letting the router handle traffic without having to deal with iptables. This method also works for commercial systems such as BlueCoat. [An example](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/CiscoIOSv15Wccp2).

2) Passive: [Bro IDS](https://www.bro.org/) - 
If you *just want to log* rather than filter websites, you may want to look into BroIDS rather than a full proxy. In this case, you will setup a server on either a network-tap, or a span-port between the router or swtich. Then the IDS will see all traffic and generate logs. Sample bro logs will look like [this](https://github.com/ThibaultReuille/semanticnet/blob/master/examples/sample/http.log).

To simplify setup, you can use a system such as [Security Onion](https://securityonion.net/) as a turnkey solution for setting up BroIDS, or one of the [pre-configured distributions for Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Support/products.html).